# Backup drive on Linux system keeps getting corrupt. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: backup, rsync, corruption, smart, debian-bullseye

My webserver (Debian BullsEye) has an internal 2TB harddrive which sole purpose is to hold a backup of the server's main HD. Every day a cronjob is started that creates a backup using rsync. But every few days, the backup drive gets corrupted and backups fail. Doing an fsck gives me tons of errors like

```
Entry 'de_language_import.lng' in /backup.2/backup.1/usr/local/ispconfig/interface/web/admin/lib/lang (24910326) has deleted/unused inode 18221087.  Clear?

Free blocks count wrong for group #2226 (2, counted=18).

Free inodes count wrong for group #2224 (541, counted=557).
```

And lots more.

I then go to reformat the drive, after which backups succeed for a few days, after which the drive gets corrupted again.

I've checked the drives SMART data and it shows the HD in perfect health. I also did a

```
badblocks -v /dev/sdb1 > badsectors.txt
```

which results in an empty badsectors.txt file (which I assume means no bad sectors were found).

And that concludes my knowledge of trying to figure out what could be wrong with the HD. So my question is: what else can I do to figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: Check cabling. Mount the drive to some different SATA port or cheap attached SATA controller.

Comment: Look with journalctl for error messages concerning the path to the drive, such as resets. You might be able to force the sata speed lower to cope with poor or noisy cabling.